# app crashing because of 'Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException' error

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, sms, broadcastreceiver

I've created an application with two activities and an SMS Receiver class. The aim of the application is to change the state of certain things within both activities when specific text/SMS messages are received e.g. check a CheckBox or toggle a ToggleButton, I need it to do this even if both activities have not been opened. For example, the app may receive a text message that tells the app to change the state of a toggle button in activity one and activity two, the problem being that if activity two has not yet been opened then it will crash the app(if activity two is opened prior to this then it will not crash). I need the app to do as it should even if activity two has not been opened. When the app crashes i get this error in logcat
     `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` 
this happens on line 187 of my receiver class (this is where I change the state of a toggle button in activity two)
Now my guess is that this is because activity two has not yet been opened, the buttons and other things within activity two have not yet been initialized/identified and therefor the receiver does not know what it is pointing to. 
What is a good way of getting around this? Is there a way of opening the second activity in the background when the app first launches? or should I be declaring my toggle buttons else where?
 
I'm quite new to this so any feedback would be great! thanks!

Receiver class:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    Global.SMSarray = new char[20];
    Global.controlNumAr = new char[11];
    //Global.controlNumAr = Global.controlNum.toCharArray();



    if (extras ==null)
        return;


    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");

    for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
        SmsMessage SMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        Global.sender = SMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
        String body = SMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
        Global.SMSarray = body.toCharArray();


        Intent in = new Intent("SmsMessage.intent.MAIN").putExtra("get_msg", Global.sender+":"+body);
        if (PhoneNumberUtils.compare(Global.controlNum, Global.sender)){

if((Global.SMSarray[0]=='O')&&(Global.SMSarray[1]=='K')){
                Toast toast= Toast.makeText(context, "OK",     

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, -100);
                toast.show();
                this.abortBroadcast();
                    }

else{
            //Zone A
            if(Global.SMSarray[12]=='a'){
                Global.mytbSA.setChecked(false);
                Global.mytbSGA.setChecked(false);

                Global.BarA.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Global.mytbSA.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Global.BarGA.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Global.mytbSGA.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                Global.setAButton.setEnabled(true);
                Global.unsetAButton.setEnabled(false);

                this.abortBroadcast();
                context.sendBroadcast(in);
                }

            else if (Global.SMSarray[12]=='A'){
                Global.mytbSA.setChecked(true);
                Global.mytbSGA.setChecked(true);

                Global.BarA.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Global.mytbSA.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Global.BarGA.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Global.mytbSGA.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                Global.setAButton.setEnabled(false);
                Global.unsetAButton.setEnabled(true);

                this.abortBroadcast();
                context.sendBroadcast(in);
                };
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: It will be batter to post your code and error log then explaining it.

Comment: posted my receiver class

Comment: It's not really the same question, I came to the conclusion that what I was asking in my first question was wrong....

Comment: also your comment does not help and is useless to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you are are getting exception on something like this code

```
your_toggle_button.setChecked(true);
```

The above code is in other class rather than your_toggle_button activity because you can't touch your activity's child if the activity is not running, to achieve this you will have to save your value in some variable and send it through intent when you start activity of that view and get that value there in that activity and change state of the view accordingly.

**So Always keep in mind you can't touch any activity's view when activity is not running and even when you didn't initialize the view**

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful. So would it be possible to start the second activity in the background when the app is first launched?

Comment: What you want first activity in foreground and same time second in background? If yes then **it is not possible**

Comment: Would it be possible to start activity 2 on launch and then switch straight to activity 1?

Comment: Yes for that you have to declare Activity 2 as launcher activity in manifest file